# How could I remove slash from a url in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

How could I remove trailing slash in front of a url? For example: stackoverflow.com/hello works on server, which definitely redirects to page named hello, but actually this is not the case on localhost.

However, it ends up something like localhost/hello instead of folder name included in it,Expected result would be localhost/stackoverflow/hello.

```
<a href="/hello" />
```

Expected output: `localhost/stackoverflow/hello`

Output got: `localhost/hello`

Actually this stuff is working on a live website but not on localhost. o I was looking for some tips to make it this way with .htaccess file.

HTACCESS FILE

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

PS: I have more than 40 files, So I don't think removing "/" from every url makes sense.

Comment: Did I misunderstand this somehow... but if you have something that starts with `/`, it means the root, not the current directory. It works the same way in domains too, but your case is not the same, one has subdir and the other doesn't.

Comment: If you use a link that starts with a `/`, you clearly state you want to link to some ressource on the root level. Are you looking for `<base href>`?

Comment: use `RewriteBase /stackoverflow/` in your .htaccess file

Comment: _“I have more than 40 files, So I don't think removing "/" from every url makes sense.”_ - perhaps learning the basics of how relative URLs work before creating those 40 files would have made sense then.

Comment: @04FS having 40 files inside the sub folder of a folder makes sense and creating duplicate file each time by the sake of using of relative url doesn't make any sense especially in a dynamic websites. That stufff actually worked on live website.so I don't think, I need to learn the basics of  how relative URL works..

Comment: _“so I don't think, I need to learn the basics of how relative URL works”_ - yes you do, because if you actually knew, you would not have been surprised by this happening, as you appear to be: _“Expected output: localhost/stackoverflow/hello”_ - no, that is _not_ what anyone who knew how relative URLs work, would have expected. `stackoverflow.com/hello` works, because there are no folders in the URL path here. `localhost/stackoverflow/hello` however does have one, and since your URL is _relative to the domain root_, this does not work then in that situation.

Comment: So you either need to change your links - or your local development setup. With a VHost mapping a local test domain directly to the `stackoverflow` folder in the file system as its domain root, `/hello` would work again.